# Login Cookies across Subdomain Requires Clearing Browser Cache

Tags: vb.net, cookies, browser-cache

I am having a problem with users needing to clear their cache every time they log in. The cookies are setup like this when they log in:

```
   Dim CompanyIDCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("CompanyID", ofRecord.CompanyID)
   Dim EmployeeIDCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("EmployeeID", EmployeeID)

   CompanyIDCookie.Domain = ".example.com"
   EmployeeIDCookie.Domain = ".example.com"

   Response.Cookies.Add(CompanyIDCookie)
   Response.Cookies.Add(EmployeeIDCookie)
```

The base page contains the following code to make sure the cookie is set. If they are company 1 (our beta testers) they are redirected to our test site instead of the main one and logged in.

```
    Dim CompanyIDCookie = Request.Cookies("CompanyID")

    If CompanyIDCookie Is DBNull.Value Then ' Don't have cookies - redirect to login
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
    If CompanyIDCookie Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If

    currentCompanyID = Request.Cookies("CompanyID").Value

    If currentCompanyID = 1 Then
        If Request.Url.OriginalString.Contains("login.example.com") Then
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace("login.example.com", "testing.example.com"))
        End If
    End If
```

However, a number of our beta testers need to clear their browser cache each time they login. Eitherwise it just keeps redirecting them to the login page.

It is not browser specific and doesn't apply to all beta users. Why do they need to keep re-clearing their cache? The Domain on the Cookies are set at Root level and it doesn't apply to all users. Users that are not in Company 1 (Beta testers) are not having the issue. Any help would be appreciated.